# Apache Tuscany SCA Java Tutorial : not able to display the list on UI

Tags: java, webservice-client, sca, apache-tuscany

I need to implement webservice clien using apache tuscany SCA. Hence I start to learn it. I refer to this tutorial : http://tuscany.apache.org/build-your-first-web-services-with-tuscany.html

I followed all as mentioned in tutorial. And yes, successfully displayed on the browser. But, the catalog list is not showed up.

In browser i see this error log for js :

```
Message: 'tuscany' is undefined Line: 8 Char: 2 Code: 0
Message: 'catalog' is null or not an object Line: 96 Char: 3 Code: 0
```

And also the html file for Line 8 under function catalog_getResponse(items):

```
//@Reference
var catalog = new tuscany.sca.Reference("catalog");
```

and this is html line 96

```
catalog.get(catalog_getResponse);
```

this is my .composite

```
<component name="Catalog">
    <implementation.java class="services.CatalogImpl" />
    <property name="currencyCode">USD</property>
    <service name="Catalog">
        <t:binding.jsonrpc uri="http://localhost:8080/Catalog"/>
    </service>
    <reference name="currencyConverter" target="CurrencyConverter" />
</component>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you were using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/store
```

This URL should turn to page "store.html", but your browser cannot reach the "store.js" file.

Thus you must use the URL below to get the catalog list showed up:

```
http://localhost:8080/store/store.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package name from the class Reference:

```
//@Reference

var catalog = new Reference("catalog"); 
...
```

[More info.](http://tuscany.apache.org/sca-java-bindingjsonrpc.html)